# Use automapper to set creation time and last edit time

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

In my MVC Core 2 application i use Automapper to map from resource classes to dto classes.
Some of my dto classes inherits from a base class with this properties:

```
ID
CREATED
UPDATED
```

I create this kind of mapping for one inherited class:

```
            CreateMap<AnagraficaCompletaResource, ANAGRAFI>()
            .ForMember(d => d.CREATED, option => { option.Condition(s => {return (s.ID == 0);}); option.MapFrom(s => DateTime.Now);})
            .ForMember(d => d.UPDATED, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.Now));
```

Can I create a generic mapping for all the classes that inherit from th base class?

My resource class don't have Created and Updated properties.

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not reasonable to set `CREATED` and `UPDATED` by `Automapper`. First, the `Creation Time` should be the time when saving the record to databse instead of mapping time, second, `ANAGRAFI` is a new empty instance when mapping, you would not be able to decide whether it is create or update operation.

For standard way, you could try to set these field during `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`.

`BaseEntity`

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

`SchoolContext`

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    SetCreatedAndModified();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    SetCreatedAndModified();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void SetCreatedAndModified()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));       

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tao. I try it and it works. I found this interesting post too: https://www.meziantou.net/2017/07/03/entity-framework-core-generate-tracking-columns